# java result set halting program after execution

Tags: java, mysql, java-server

i am creating my first application in java so basically i want to add an forgot password functionality.

now what i am doing is i am creating an form and on the **POST** method i am sending three roles from drop down i.e Admin, Student , Teacher,

now on the basis of these roles i will send password in email(i will make it more secure in future) so firstly i am checking which role i have and  secondly whether the email entered on the front end actually exists i the database, here's my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.suzieloveschildren.emailContactUs.EmailUtility;
import com.suzieloveschildren.entitiesClasses.Intervenants;
import com.suzieloveschildren.entitiesClasses.Mediateurs;
import com.suzieloveschildren.implementationController.EnfantsHibernateDAO;
import com.suzieloveschildren.implementationController.IntervenantsHibernateDAO;
import com.suzieloveschildren.implementationController.MediateursHibernateDAO;
import com.suzieloveschildren.initGeneric.GenericSpringServlet;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ForgotPassword
 */
@WebServlet("/ForgotPassword")
public class ForgotPassword extends GenericSpringServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    EnfantsHibernateDAO enfantsdao;

    @Autowired
    MediateursHibernateDAO mediateursdao;

    @Autowired
    IntervenantsHibernateDAO intervenantsdao;

    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String user;
    private String pass;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/main/forgot.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        /* Mediateurs mediateurs = new Mediateurs(); */

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/suzieloveschildren";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";


        String email = request.getParameter("checkmail");
        String role = request.getParameter("checkrole");

    /*  if (role.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {

        }*/

        if (role.equals("ROLE_MED")) {

            List<Mediateurs> listofemails = mediateursdao.readAllMediateursEmails();
            String emails = listofemails.toString();
            emails = emails.replace("[", "");
            emails = emails.replace("]", "");

            boolean check = false;
            List<String> emailsforsend = Arrays.asList(emails.split(","));
            for (String em : emailsforsend) {
                // System.out.println(em);
                em = em.trim();
                if (Objects.equals(em, email)) {
                    check = true;
                }
            }

            if (!check) {
                response.sendRedirect("ForgotPassword");
            } else {

                try {
                    System.out.println(email);
                    Class.forName(driverName);
                    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                    String sql ="SELECT PASSWORD FROM mediateurs WHERE EMAIL= "+ email;
                    System.out.println(sql);
                    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    System.out.println(stmt);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    System.out.println("uneeb");

                    if (rs.next()) {

                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                        System.out.println(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));

                    }
                    /*String password2 = "TestPassword";

                    String resultMessage = "";
                    try {
                        String subject = "Email Password Sent";
                        String content = "Your password is:sefssfasasdaas  " ;
                        EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, email, subject, content);
                        resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
                        request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);
                    }*/

                     connection.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

now the section `if (role.equals("ROLE_MED"))` is where i am stuck, in the **else** condition of the **if** is where i have to fetch password from the database according to **email**(my emails are also unique) now this is the query

```
SELECT PASSWORD FROM mediateurs WHERE EMAIL="example@yahoo.com"
```

now this query works perfectly fine on **phpmyadmin** but when i try to execute it using prepared statements its like nothing happens, after the line

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

nothing executes below it not even the `System.out.println("uneeb");`
i have no idea what i did wrong , i am an absolute beginner in java i have tested many solutions from other questions but none worked for me! any help?

Comment: Put `ex.printStackTrace();` into your `catch` block.

Comment: To prevent SQL injections you should prepare with  `WHERE EMAIL = ?` and use `setString(1, email)` not with `WHERE EMAIL =" + email`.. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @PM77-1 i should kill me myself :D , i have been messing with this errors for couple of hours now, totally forgot basically exception handling

Comment: @PM77-1 i am receiving incorrect syntax error basically my email is uneeb@yhaoo.com when i pass this as mysql throws an exception that error is near '@yahoo.com' how can i pass this as an string i tried toString() doesnt work

Comment: `String sql ="SELECT PASSWORD FROM mediateurs WHERE EMAIL= '"+ email + "';"`  Or better, as it was suggested, use `prepared statement`.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks so much man,  can you put this as an answer so i can mark it?

Comment: Nah. Isn't worth it.

Comment: @PM77-1 its worth to me :) ,  either way i highly appreciate your help, keep up the good work